# Trouble using np.getfromtxt(

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ubuntu-16.04

The challenge is to read in the following data using numpy:

```
# File content:
# -------------
1,2,3,4,5
6,,,7,8
,,9,10,11
# -------------
```

The solution is:

```
Z = np.genfromtxt("missing.dat", delimiter=",")
```

But when I try this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #3 (got 5 columns instead of 1)
    Line #4 (got 5 columns instead of 1)
    Line #5 (got 5 columns instead of 1)
```

To create the .dat file required, I cut and pasted the data into a word processor (LibreOffice writer). There was no option to save a type .dat so I saved as a a text file then renamed it to .dat? Not sure if this is might be causing the problem.

Comment: Can you verify that the first character of the commented lines in the file is actually `#`?  I can reproduce the error that you get by adding the argument `comments='%'`, which makes `genfromtxt` treat the lines beginning with `#` as data. Then, since there are no commas in the first line, it treats the entire first line as a single column, and it expects all the remaining lines to have just one column.  But then it finds multiple columns in lines 3, 4, 5, and reports those as errors.

Comment: I should add that when I use the command you show with the file quoted in the question, I don't get any errors, and `Z` is created as expected.

Comment: The file is taken from question from Q 46 here: http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/numpy.100/index.html

Comment: I just cut and pasted this into a word processor (LibreOffice Writer). Unfortunately LibreOffice does not have the option to save as .dat so I had to manually rename to .dat is maybe that this is causing the error?

Comment: How did you create the .dat file to test this?

Comment: I copied it into an editor (Sublime Text) and saved it.  I strongly recommend that you don't use a word processor such as LibreOffice Writer for editing programs.  Any basic plain text editor should be fine, but an editor designed for writing code will be much better in the long run.

Comment: That was it! It works when I used Sublime text to produce the .dat file!